# C# Entity Framework using class from model in a query slower than using anonymous class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 5 to access my DB. The model is quite complex with a lot of navigation properties. I have written the following query using linq:

```
var myQuery =
        from cp in context.ClosedPositions.Include("Position").Include("Position.Folder").Include("Position.Strategy").Include("Position.Symbol").Include("Position.StopTargetPlacer")
        where cp.Position.EntryDate >= fromDT &&
        cp.ExitDate <= toDT &&
        (cp.Position.Folder.FolderCode == myFolder || showAllFolders) &&
        (cp.Position.Strategy.Name == myStrategy || showAllStrategies) &&
        (cp.Position.Symbol.Name == mySymbol || showAllSymbols) &&
        (cp.Position.Symbol.Exchange == myExchange || showAllExchanges)
        orderby cp.Position.EntryDate
        select cp;
```

The navigations multiplicity are the following:

Position 1 - * ClosedPostion

Position * - 1 Folder

Position * - 1 Strategy

Position * - 1 Symbol

Then in a foreach query I use the Data from the Included navigation properties. I think this way should not hit the database more than once. The query runs for about 6 seconds.

Then I have rewritten the query to this:

```
var myQuery =
        from cp in context.ClosedPositions
        join p in context.Positions on cp.PositionID equals p.ID
        join f in context.Folders on p.FolderID equals f.ID
        join sy in context.Symbols on p.SymbolID equals sy.ID
        join st in context.Strategies on p.StrategyID equals st.ID
        join stp in context.StopTargetPlacers on p.StopTargetPlacerID equals stp.ID
        where p.EntryDate >= fromDT &&
        cp.ExitDate <= toDT &&
        (f.FolderCode == myFolder || showAllFolders) &&
        (st.Name == myStrategy || showAllStrategies) &&
        (sy.Name == mySymbol || showAllSymbols) &&
        (sy.Exchange == myExchange || showAllExchanges)
        orderby p.EntryDate
        select new
        {
              ClosedPositionID = cp.ID,
              PositionID = p.ID,
              p.EntryChartID,
              cp.ExitChartID,
              p.EntryDate,
              cp.ExitDate,
              Symbol = sy.Name,
              Strategy = st.Name,
              p.Size,
              cp.Profit,
              STPlacer = p.StopTargetPlacer.Name,
              InitialRisk = p.InitialRisk,
              StrategyDirection = st.Direction
         };
```

Again I have used the same foreach loop to work on the data. This time the total processing time was only around 1 second.

I have examined the generated SQL queries by both LINQ query in running them in the SSMS both of them returned the same data in the same amount of time.

My question is why is there the huge delay between using an anonymous class and a class from the model of the context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many records are we talking about?
Have you disabled Entity Tracking at the context level?

Remember that when EF materializes an entity with tracking enabled it has to check every record coming from the database to make sure it does not materialize the same object again. Also tracking an entity is more expensive because it has to register all the entities (more code execution).
When you materialize an anonymous type the context does not worry about all this.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem as I have already posted an answer about that. Took me a while to figure it out as I havent been using a lot of EF.

Answer (score 2):

Ok after some research I found out that the problem is that in the first case in the background the EF builds up the change tracking structure and in the second case since I am using an anonymous class this will not happen. The solution was the AsNoTracking function:

```
var myQuery =
    from cp in context.ClosedPositions.Include("Position").AsNoTracking().Include("Position.Folder").Include("Position.Strategy").Include("Position.Symbol").Include("Position.StopTargetPlacer")
    where cp.Position.EntryDate >= fromDT &&
    cp.ExitDate <= toDT &&
    (cp.Position.Folder.FolderCode == myFolder || showAllFolders) &&
    (cp.Position.Strategy.Name == myStrategy || showAllStrategies) &&
    (cp.Position.Symbol.Name == mySymbol || showAllSymbols) &&
    (cp.Position.Symbol.Exchange == myExchange || showAllExchanges)
    orderby cp.Position.EntryDate
    select cp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the first query is going to basically pull back every property on the entities that are used in the navigation properties even if you don't want them and the second query is using projection so its only going to retrieve those properties you have specifically asked for in your query... in this instance only the Strategy name for example and ignores everything else that may belong to a strategy.

Although this is over simplified... imagine the following scenario... (MyTable has X number of columns)

First Query is much like:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
```

Where as projection enables EF to be alot more specific...

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM MyTable
```

And that is why you are experiencing a much faster query.

Comment: Maybe he should try the same projection in the first query as in the second query... (also I think the projection will disable change tracking since there is no entity to track - in his response he indicated it helped).